# Socketio specific client join room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I know that I can use

```
socket.join(room);
```

But it's not what I want.
I want to choose specific client connected to server and make him join room.
So it would looks like that:

```
OpEhq_0m7wzkZenVAAAB.join(room)
```

Where `OpEhq_0m7wzkZenVAAAB` is a single client.

Comment: What about `if (socket.id === "OpEhq_0m7wzkZenVAAAB") { socket.join(room) }` ? ;)

Comment: But how can I iterate over connected sockets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make client join room you have to get clients object then you can join using that,to get that clients object you have to store clients object in array on connection like this,

```
var i;
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    array[i]=socket;
    i++;
}
```

afterwards if you want to make specific client join room you can do,

```
array[0].join(room);
array[1].join(room);
```

Hope it will help..!

Comment: so if you get millions of users memory footprint will grow. Any idea how to do it efficiently ?

Comment: I use to remove the user object from an array when the user disconnects.